# Can we estimate $R^2$ for logistic regression using only summary statistic of each predicting variable?

Tags: regression, logistic, linear, r-squared

A toy example:
We aim to predict the onset of stroke by body weight and age. We know that:

1. 1-SD increment of weight increases the risk of stroke by 20% i.e. standardized coefficient of regression stroke~weight+intercept is log(1.2)
2. 1-SD increment of age increases the risk of stroke by 15%
3. Pearson correlation between weight and age is 0.1
4. The prevalence of stroke in the population is 1%

Is it possible to estimate the $R^2$ value of following logistic regression, without individual-level data:
stroke~weight+age+intercept

If not, what else information should we obtain?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: No, you need to know the relationship between the predictors and the outcome, not just the marginal distributions. However, $R^2$ does not have the usual interpretation in a nonlinear model, such as logistic regression, so it might not be as useful as you expect. Why do you want the $R^2$?

Comment: No. You can do pseudo R square or VFU

Comment: @Dave seems like I messed up with R2 of linear regression, so is it possible to estimate the proportion of variance of outcome explained by the predictors? I'm not sure whether this proportion is associated with logistic regression. Thanks!

Comment: I’m not sure I understand what you’re asking, but if you’re wondering about some kind of $R^2$ “proportion of variance explained” for logistic regression, rather than determining the $R^2$ from the information you provided, that warrants its own question.